# Regex to allow 1.00, .10, or 10. but not allow a single decimal

Tags: java, regex, validation, pattern-matching, match

I have been trying to figure out the regular expression validation for my java program that will allow the following currency values "1", "1.00", ".1", or "1." but not a single decimal ".".

The digits before or after the decimal (if it exists) can be any length.

What I have is

```
(([\d]*\.)?[\d]*)
```

but that allows a single decimal without any numbers before or after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.

```
\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rS3aG4/11)

Use `String#matches()` method to match it.

sample code:

```
String regex="\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\d*\\.?\\d+";

System.out.println("1".matches(regex));   // true
System.out.println("1.00".matches(regex));// true
System.out.println(".1".matches(regex));  // true
System.out.println("1.".matches(regex));  // true

System.out.println(".".matches(regex));   // false
```

Comment: This matches `1.2foo` or `foo.1`, unless you use the `.matches()` method (in which case you don't need `^` or `$`.

Comment: I don;t think so `^` and `$` is added

Comment: @TimPietzcker try `System.out.println("1.2foo".matches(regex));` return `false`

Comment: You don't need the ^ or $ if you're using `matches()` - they are implied.

Comment: @Bohemian yes I agree just added to give it a meaning. I have edited it back to my last edit.

Comment: OK, now it only fails on `10.00` and higher amounts (if there's more than one decimal digit)...

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes I agree it fails for this case. Just edited the post.

Comment: @TimPietzcker more than one decimal is not a valid number.

Comment: Why so complicated? `\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.\d+`

Comment: @TimPietzcker OK I got it.

Comment: @Bohemian yes there are lots of ways to write it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mine is the shortest

Comment: I just bench marked mine at 3 microseconds using String.matches() and .7 microseconds reusing a compiled Pattern. Fast enough?

Comment: I have edited my post and I think its more simple and faster?

Answer (score 1):

This regex does what you need:

```
(?!\.?$)\d*\.?\d*
```

It uses a simple pattern with a negative look ahead to exclude the degenerate cases.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/9PRCvs2drb)

---

Java code demo:

```
for (String s : new String[] { "1", "1.", ".1", "111", ".", "foo" })
    System.out.format("%3s : %b\n", s, s.matches("(?!\\.?$)\\d*\\.?\\d*"));
```

Output:

```
  1 : true
 1. : true
 .1 : true
111 : true
  . : false
foo : false
```

---

A question arose regarding performance. Well using a crappy old notebook, with JVM warm up, using `String#matches()` was 3 microseconds and reusing a compiled `Pattern` (ie `pattern.matcher(s).matches()`) was 0.7 microseconds.

Comment: The more interesting question regarding performance would be: This pattern versus Braj's pattern which does not use lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, depending on where and how you use this, would be [`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) and catch the [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). This will allow you to accept exactly those numbers java can use.

```
boolean isDecimal(String str) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This does not exactly answer your question, but might still help you.

Comment: I can not vote down your answer but I would if I could: There is nothing uglier than using a try-catch to do an if-else! It creates useless objects (at least the NumberFormatException) and it is slow. Even saying "where and how you use this" nobody should give such bad idea.

Comment: Thats your opinion, and your are entitled to it. There are people who prefer exception based coded and those who don't. The facts are questionable though: Whether this has more overhead than the other approach depends on whether you actually need the number (which you might), in this case my approach will be more efficient

Comment: I am not against exceptions based code and I did not say to avoid exceptions. Your "solution" is not an exception based code, this is just a bad use of exceptions. Maybe you will understand what I want to say with another example: `boolean isNull(Object o) { try { o.toString(); return false; } catch (NullPointerException npe) { return true; } }` instead of `return o == null`. _(End of discussion for me because you gave me the impression to not wanting to understand what is wrong with this kind of "exception management".)_